# If you gain 200 rep on any overflow site, will this increase 100 rep points on all other sites you've already joined?

Tags: support, reputation, association, association-bonus

Or does it only apply to ones you haven't joined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Saying it with other words, it is retroactive; it is applied to the accounts you already have, and the accounts you will create in the future.
The bonus is gained once for each site, and it is always 100, independently from the number of sites where you have a reputation higher than 199.

Comment: So, If I gain 200 rep on site A, then go from 100 to 200 rep. on site B, does that make me have 300 rep. on site A?

Comment: If site A is the first site where you reach a reputation of 200, then your reputation or site A becomes 300, and your reputation on site B becomes 300 because the reputation on site A; on site B, your reputation doesn't become 400.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I think the scenario he was asking, is if he has 100 rep on B & gets another 100 from A (hence total reaches 200) - does this result in another +100 on site A, which did not benefit from its own bonus boost.

Comment: @Alok In that case, no; the reputation for getting the bonus is on a single SE site. If I reach a reputation of 200 on Stack Overflow, then I get a bonus of 100 points on Stack Overflow, and any SE site I have, and will have an account. If I have a reputation of 100 on Stack Overflow, and 100 on Super User, then I don't get the bonus reputation.

Answer (score 8):

It applies to both - the ones which you have joined, but haven't gotten the association rep bonus as well as future sites that you will join