# How did my Stack Overflow reputation increase from 196 to 300?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did my SO rep just jump by 100?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97635/why-did-my-so-rep-just-jump-by-100)

My Stack Overflow account reputation increased from 196 to 300.
How did it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your [reputation audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation).

It looks like your SO account just went over 200 points, so your [associated account bonus (100 points) probably kicked in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98038/if-you-gain-200-rep-on-any-overflow-site-will-this-increase-100-rep-points-on-al/98040#98040).

Comment: You sure it's kicking in automatically? Sounds little weird to me.

Comment: @Shadow: No, I'm not sure.  But: (1) other posts, like the one I linked, state that it's retroactive.  (2) it makes sense, since [his associated accounts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/160385/talespin-kit?tab=accounts) are all more than a week old, and he just now got over 200 rep on any one account.

Comment: Fair enough, but he also got accounts in two more SE sites - so why not 300 reputation gain, just 100? BTW congrats for 2K rep! :)

Comment: You only get the 100 rep once on each site.

Comment: Yes, each one of his accounts got 100 points, once the *first* one went over 200 points. Maybe the OP will run the rep audit and fill us in on the blanks.  Also, thanks!  And congrats yourself -- having reached the 2K level long ago.

Answer (score 2):

You get 100 reputation when [associating accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56461/why-do-we-get-rep-points-on-associating-our-accounts) - did you by any chance only now associated your Meta account with your SO account?

This reputation boost is not visible anywhere as far as I could see, so I can't really be sure this explain your case.

Comment: no i did not associate any account.

Comment: I saw you accepted Brock answer, so what was it then? :)